# Unable to create shared library(JNI based) which depends on android build library to use it in my android application

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I wanted to create a shared library(JNI based) which is depending android build shared libraries(bluetooth lib), I am unable to create it from android ndk source(android-ndk-r5b),

Is there any way that I can create shared library with in the android source itself, I found (android-donut/development/ndk) folder, can I create my library by using this ndk folder.

please check my current Android.mk file.

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog
LOCAL_MODULE    := keypad
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES:= libbluedroid
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_test_keypad_TestClass.c ,com_test_keypad_TestClass.h
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

libbluedroid - is the library from android build which I need to use for my shared library.